# Choosing a variable from a generated number

Tags: javascript, variables

Using javascript I have a few variables.

```
var item1 = {
    name : 'apple',
    color : 'red',
    type : 'fruit'
    //etc
};
var item2 = {
    name : 'rose',
    color : 'red',
    type : 'plant'
    //etc
};
```

I would like to select said items based on a number.  I thought to do it like this.

```
var select;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

select = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
```

However I'm having trouble calling to those items.  I thought it would just be `item[select].name` etc.. however its clearly not happening.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

Put your items in an array:

```
items = [item1, item2];
```

Next, select (print out) a random item's name using your getRandomInt() function:

```
console.log(items[getRandomInt(0,items.length - 1)].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your items in one array rather than using multiple variables:

```
var items = [
    {
        name: 'apple',
        // ...
    },
    {
        name: 'cherry',
        // ...
    }
];

// Pick a random item (slightly biased)
var item = items[Math.random() ℅ items.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

- Store the objects in an array
- Improve the random generator.

```js
var item = [{
  name: 'apple',
  color: 'red',
  type: 'fruit'
}, {
  name: 'rose',
  color: 'red',
  type: 'plant'
},{
  name: 'apple1',
  color: 'red1',
  type: 'fruit1'
}, {
  name: 'rose1',
  color: 'red1',
  type: 'plant1'
}];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

console.log(item[getRandomInt(0, item.length)].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your items in an array `items` and then use `items[select].name`

```js
var item1 = {
    name : 'apple',
    color : 'red',
    type : 'fruit'
    //etc
};
var item2 = {
    name : 'rose',
    color : 'red',
    type : 'plant'
    //etc
};

var item = [item1, item2];
var select = "";

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    select = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) ;

console.log(item[select].name);
```